# Working with scoped beans when the scope is optional?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, scope

I have a scope which sometimes doesn't exist when I need some bean from it. That in itself isn't a problem; I could use defaults for these cases. My problem is with autowiring. The scenarios goes roughly like this:

1. I have a scoped bean `ICurrentLocale`. It's scope is `User` and the scope depends on whether a user is currently logged in.
2. Autowire bean `foo` contains a field `@Autowired ICurrentLocale currentLocale;`
3. Call some methods on `foo`.
4. A user logs in. Now, I have a scope `User`
5. Call some methods on `foo`.

My problem is that in point #5, the autowired `ICurrentLocale` bean is still the same despite the fact that a new bean has created in the user's scope.

Is there a good/simple/understandable way to build a spring configuration that automatically rewires beans when a new scope is entered in the same thread?

Or maybe I can ask Spring to "refresh" the proxy?

**EDIT** Here is my current implementation of the scope:

```
@Override
public Object get( String name, final ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory ) {
    CurrentUserSession currentSession = userSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    if( currentSession == null ) {
        if( isLocaleProvider( name ) ) {
            return createLocaleProvider();
        }
        throw new BeanCreationException( "Could not create bean " + name + " the bean scope " + NAME + " can be used only after the user has signed in" );
    }

    Object bean = currentSession.getBean(name, objectFactory);
    return bean;
}
```

As you can see, I create a dummy bean as long as no user is logged in. If I have a session, I look into the cache in the session. If the bean doesn't exist, yet, I use the `objectFactory` to create a new one.

Comment: Show us your `UserScope` implementation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Here you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.

Your `ICurrentLocale` bean should be something like

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "user", proxy-mode = "ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS")
public class CurrentLocaleImpl implements ICurrentLocale {
   ...
}
```

or the corresponding `@Bean` or XML configuration.

With such configuration, Spring will create a proxy for your injection target. In other words, in

```
@Autowired
private ICurrentLocale currentLocale;
```

you won't have a `CurrentLocaleImpl` object, you'll have a proxy object that has a reference to the underlying `BeanFactory`.

> 5.Call some methods on foo.
>
> My problem is that in point #5, the autowired `ICurrentLocale` bean is
>   still the same despite the fact that a new bean has created in the
>   user's scope.

When you invoke a method on the proxy bean, the proxy will attempt to retrieve an actual `CurrentLocaleImpl` object from the `BeanFactory` using your `Scope` implementation and then delegate the method call to that object. Effectively, you'll be using either the proper object, the default object, or throwing an exception.

Comment: I think I begin to understand my misconception. Just to clarify: When the bean is autowired, a proxy is injected but at that time, my user scope is not called - the bean remains a proxy without an attached instance. Then, when I call the first *method* on the bean, a proxy lookup is done. This is the first time `get()` of my scope is called. Is this correct?

Comment: @Aaron Mostly correct. At all times, the injected object is always the proxy (it's Java after all and Spring only processes the `foo` bean once). Now, _every time_ you invoke a method on this object, a lookup is done with your `UserScope#get(..)`. You can cache the actual instance there, or you can look it up on every invocation.

Comment: With this explanation, I could find the bug: Some helper framework created a new thread and when code in this thread was executed, `userSessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` couldn't find the session ... :-P

Answer (score 0):

For other people with similar problems: Make sure `userSessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` returns what you expect.

In my case, the user session is attached to the current thread (using `ThreadLocal`). Now a helper framework executed some of my code in a new background thread -> `ThreadLocal` returned `null` despite me knowing that a user was logged in.